# Recursion in a single MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, loops, recursion, subquery

I have set up a network/tree and now, starting at one node, I'm trying to select all nodes that lie between this one and another node – all in one query.

Assume two tables, one for storing objects with attributes and one for storing their (direct) relationships. Let's keep the example simple.

```
CREATE TABLE objects (id varchar(64) PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO objects VALUES ('seat'), ('chair'), ('furniture'), ('barstool'), ('stool');

CREATE TABLE parentships ( parent varchar(64) NOT NULL, child varchar(64) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (parent, child), CONSTRAINT fk_child FOREIGN KEY (child) REFERENCES objects (id), CONSTRAINT fk_parent FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES objects (id) );
INSERT INTO parentships VALUES ('furniture', 'seat'), ('seat', 'chair'), ('seat', 'stool'), ('stool', 'barstool');
```

Furniture is the root/end node. Let me try to visualize this small network/tree.

```
furniture --- seat -+- chair
                    |
                    +- stool --- barstool
```

I assume that I need to create a recursion with `SUBSELECT`, `LOOP` and procedures but I've never used `LOOP` nor self-made procedures before. Maybe you can help me explain things while I'll continue to search/try on my own.

```
{magic query (parameter 'barstool')}

+-----------+
| parent    |
+-----------+   <--- This is what I want.
| stool     |
| chair     |
| seat      |
| furniture |
+-----------+
```

I've already figured out a way to manually do the first two steps of iterations.

```
SET @p = '';
SET @p = ( SELECT parent FROM parentships WHERE child IN ('barstool', @p) );

SELECT parent FROM parentships WHERE child IN ('barstool', @p);
```

But the documentation for loops is confusing me. This is my attempt but I'm getting error messages:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE find_all_ancestors(node varchar)
BEGIN
  SET @p = '';
  label1: LOOP
    SET @p = ( SELECT parent FROM parentships WHERE child IN (node, @p) );
    IF @p != 'furniture' THEN
      ITERATE label1
    END IF
    LEAVE label1
  END LOOP label1
  SET @x = @p
END
```

But I'm getting several error messages, starting with this one:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'label1: LOOP
    SET @p = ( SELECT parent FROM parentships WHERE child ' at line 4
```

Also, I would need to add the iterated @p to an array of intermediate results anyway and MySQL doesn't allow arrays. So maybe I'm using the wrong approach altogether.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below version - this is your code just slightly modified. 
After executing it returns comma delimited list with respective values.

I have placed also some comments into the code.

```
DELIMITER // /* It enables the ; delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed through to the server rather than being interpreted by mysql itself*/

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS find_all_ancestors // 

CREATE PROCEDURE find_all_ancestors(node varchar(100)) # /*Need to define number of characters for varchar */

BEGIN

  SET @p = node;
  SET @s = '';
  SET @pc = '';
  SET @c = 0;

  label1: LOOP

    IF @p != 'furniture' AND @p IN (@s) = 0 THEN

        SET @c = @c + 1;

        SET @p = ( SELECT parent FROM parentships WHERE child IN (@p) LIMIT 1 );

        SET @s = CONCAT(@s,',',@p);

        IF @c = 2 AND @p IN (@s) = 0 THEN

            SET @pc = ( SELECT child FROM parentships WHERE parent IN (@p) LIMIT 1 );

            SET @s = CONCAT(@s,',',@pc);

        END IF;

        ITERATE label1;

    END IF;

    LEAVE label1;

  END LOOP label1;

    SELECT SUBSTRING(@s,2,100) AS RESULT FROM DUAL; 

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Once you create the procedure you can run it:

```
CALL find_all_ancestors('barstool');
```

Also look for some stuff about hierarchical retrieval - https://www.google.com/search?q=hierarchical+retrieval+in+mysql. It could be helpful for you.

There are many others ways of doing this kind of things. Depending on you needs.

Comment: Sorry to let you wait so long but in an attempt to upgrade my PHP configuration I broke my XAMPP and now I can't access my MySQL stuff until that's fixed. — Your approach _looks_ like it's exactly what I was searching for, though. Thanks especially for the in-code comments.

Comment: Sorry for getting back at you so late, but this is exactly what I ended up setting up and using often (without remembering what a challenge it had been to set up). Question answered.